# Why is the following template declaration ill-formed?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, standards

Why is the following declaration invalid?

```
template<template<typename> typename T>
struct S {};
```

I would assume this was valid since the following is valid:

```
template<template<typename> class T>
struct S {};
```

and what I can read from the standard in [gram.temp] it appears to be valid, but gcc gives me the following output:

```
prog.cpp:4:38: error: expected 'class' before 'T'
 template<template<typename> typename T>
                                  ^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, "because the standard says so." C++11 14.1/1 lists the syntax for *type-parameter:*

> *type-parameter:*
>     `class` `...`<sub>*opt*</sub> *identifier*<sub>*opt*</sub>
>     `class` *identifier*<sub>*opt*</sub> `=` *type-id*
>     `typename` `...`<sub>*opt*</sub> *identifier*<sub>*opt*</sub>
>     `typename` *identifier*<sub>*opt*</sub> `=` *type-id*
>     `template` `<` *template-parameter-list* `>` `class` `...`<sub>*opt*</sub> *identifier*<sub>*opt*</sub>
>     `template` `<` *template-parameter-list* `>` `class` *identifier*<sub>*opt*</sub> `=` *id-expression*

As you can see, only `class` is allowed for template template parameters.

My guess for the rationale is that any type can be used as a type argument, including non-class types. But before C++11, there was no such thing as a "non-class type template"—the only type templates were class templates.

This has changed with C++11's alias templates, but the template template parameter syntax has obviously not kept up. Nevertheless, in a post-C++11 (actually post-C++14) [draft N4296](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf), this restriction is actually lifted and `template <class> typename` is valid template template parameter syntax.

Comment: In N4296 it's specified differently though. In 14.1/1 in http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf it appears to be different. Does this mean this restriction is going to change?

Comment: @MathiasVorreiterPedersen Apparently so.

Comment: *"the only type templates are class templates."* Alias templates

Comment: @Columbo Just addressed it

Comment: while technically true that it's a "post-C++11" draft, n4296 is also post-C++14. It's the most recent version of the C++1z

Comment: The paper proposing this change is [N4051](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2014/n4051.html), which was [EWG issue 131](http://cplusplus.github.io/EWG/ewg-complete.html#131).